# Meu footer não aparece na primeira página quando meu pdf tem várias páginas, apenas a partir da segunda - Laravel 8 DomPDF

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-blade, dompdf, laravel-8

Olá, boa noite. Criei um layout para estar gerando os meus relatórios em **PDF**, neste layout o **header** e o **footer** são **fixos**, porque quero que eles se repitam em **todas as páginas**. Entretanto, quando o **PDF** gera várias páginas o footer começa a aperecer apenas na **segunda página**. Um adendo, quando tenho apenas uma página o **footer** aparece corretamente. Já li algumas perguntas parecidas aqui na comunidade, mas nada que resolvesse este meu problema. Desde já, agradeço.

**Versão do DomPDF que estou usando**:
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

**Meu código:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="/public/assets/css/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Teste para Relatório</title>
    <style>
        @page {
            margin: 100px 25px;
        }

        /* HEADER */

        #header {
            position: fixed;
            top: -60px;
            left: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: #03a9f4;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 35px;
        }

        .table-header {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }



        /* MAIN */

        #main {
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }

        .table-main {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            table-layout: fixed;
        }

        .table-main tr {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .table-main td,
        .table-main th {
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }



        /* FOOTER */

        #footer {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: -60px;
            left: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: #03a9f4;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 35px;
        }

        .table-footer {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="" id="header">
        <table class="table-header">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    TOPO !!!
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="" id="main">
        <table class="table-main">
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">
                    Nº Lab.
                </th>
                <th rowspan="2">
                    Identificação Amostra
                </th>
                <th>
                    Argila
                </th>
                <th>
                    Areia
                </th>
                <th>
                    Silte
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>%</td>
                <td>%</td>
                <td>%</td>
            </tr>
            @foreach ($physical as $item)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $item->numero_lab_physical_analyses }}</td>
                    <td>
                        @foreach ($deep as $value)
                            @if ($value->deep_id === $value->id)
                                {{ $value->name }}
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="" id="footer">
        <table class="table-footer">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    BASE !!!
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Devido à maneira como o dompdf analisa/renderiza documentos, qualquer posição absoluta/fixa de CSS ou conteúdo page_text() de script embutido é renderizado a partir da página em que são encontrados. Portanto, se esse conteúdo estiver na parte inferior do documento, ele será renderizado apenas na última página. Logo, a solução é colocar o footer logo abaixo do header.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="/public/assets/css/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Teste para Relatório</title>
    <style>
        @page {
            margin: 100px 25px;
        }

        /* HEADER */

        #header {
            position: fixed;
            top: -60px;
            left: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: #03a9f4;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 35px;
        }

        .table-header {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }



        /* MAIN */

        #main {
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }

        .table-main {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            table-layout: fixed;
        }

        .table-main tr {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .table-main td,
        .table-main th {
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }



        /* FOOTER */

        #footer {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: -60px;
            left: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: #03a9f4;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 35px;
        }

        .table-footer {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="" id="header">
        <table class="table-header">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    TOPO !!!
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="" id="footer">
        <table class="table-footer">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    BASE !!!
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="" id="main">
        <table class="table-main">
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">
                    Nº Lab.
                </th>
                <th rowspan="2">
                    Identificação Amostra
                </th>
                <th>
                    Argila
                </th>
                <th>
                    Areia
                </th>
                <th>
                    Silte
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>%</td>
                <td>%</td>
                <td>%</td>
            </tr>
            @foreach ($physical as $item)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $item->numero_lab_physical_analyses }}</td>
                    <td>
                        @foreach ($deep as $value)
                            @if ($value->deep_id === $value->id)
                                {{ $value->name }}
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```